# How to Delete Rows Based on Criteria from 2 Columns in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to clean up some records by removing rows with specific locations that we don't do business with.  I would like to figure out how to write VBA code that would search through the Destination City and Destination State columns (columns L & M in my current case) and delete the records that match a specific city AND state.

I have figured out how to delete records by multiple criteria within the same column but not across columns.

```
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
With Sheets("data_export")
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Firstrow = 2
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For lRow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With .Cells(lRow, "D") 'Stops'
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value >= "1" Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With

        With .Cells(lRow, "P") 'HaZMat
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value <> "" Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With

        With .Cells(lRow, "T") 'Service
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value <> "Truck Load" Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next lRow
End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

We want to remove all rows for *Springfield, California* but keep *Springfield, Florida.*

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "L") = "Springfield" And Cells(i, "M") = "California" Then
            Cells(i, "L").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```